# International Telephone Input for Angular 9

Tags: angular, angular9

I am need to implement an input for intl mobile number in my web application, but I can hardly find any that supports Angular 9 version.
Do you have any recommendations?
Thanks

Comment: ngx-intl-tel-input now supports Angular 9

Comment: Asking for recommendations is off-topic. I don't know why so many people with close privileges chose to answer rather than close.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a better npm package(ngx-intl-tel-input) that fullfil your requirement. Please have look on it.

Here is the link to the package 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-intl-tel-input

stackblitz demo link:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-intl-tel-input-demo

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Angular material,you can use **International Telephone Input for Angular Material (NgxMatIntlTelInput)**

url : https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mat-intl-tel-input

**Supports**:
Angular Material,
ReactiveFormsModule,
FormsModule,
Validation with libphonenumber-js

Comment: Thank you, this saved me a lot of searching. The component work perfectly.

Comment: But it is mentioned that it only supports Angular version 13.

Comment: @RaminAr it supports other version Angular also.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good [validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/validator) on npm.

Use the `isMobilePhone(str [, locale [, options]])` method to validate all international phone numbers.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2023 february, the checked answer recommand a package that seem's to be discontinued. No update for 10 months, no update for Angular13+.

As a replacement i recommand this package wich is maintained and ok for Angular 14.x:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mat-intl-tel-input

Comment: I've tried using this package and the input is being displayed on the side of the screen https://prnt.sc/JmUyc_4Rt8RI

Answer (score -1):

try the following project, based on ngx-intl-tel-input.

using angular 16.4.1 and Bootstrap 5.3
[ngx-bs-tel-input](https://github.com/hezyz/ngx-bs-tel-input)

[image]